# How to make a dynamic global variable in java

Tags: java, oop

Hello I am new to java and I wanted to make a variable that would be an object of different classes based on a string condition. I am not sure how to do that.

Here is what I am trying to explain

```
public class Foo {
    Object obj; // I want this variable to be dynamic based on the condition in the constructor
    public Foo(String str){ // Constructor
        if(str.equals("bar")){
            this.obj = new Bar();
        }
        else{
            this.obj = new Baz();
        }
    }
```

I want it this way because I will be using this obj variable later on to call methods in either Bar or Baz which both implement the methods of same name, but different code.

Comment: It sounds like Bar and Baz should both implement a common interface...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Comment: Thanks to both of you a lot, I had never heard of interface before, it fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this java code, You will understand how to use interfaces to resolve this problem

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
        foo.obj.hello();
    }
}

class Foo {
    Ba obj;

    Foo(String str) { // Constructor
        if (str.equals("bar")) {
            this.obj = new Bar();
        } else {
            this.obj = new Baz();
        }
    }
}

interface Ba {
    void hello();
}

class Bar implements Ba {
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println(" Hello Bar");
    }
}

class Baz implements Ba {
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println(" Hello Baz");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the strategy pattern, here's a crude implememntation:

```
public class Foo {
    Map<String, Common> strategyPattern = new HashMap<>();

    private Common obj;

    {
        // set this up how you want, this is a static code block common to all classes 
        // if you're using spring you can autowire these
        // Bar and Baz both implement Common interface
        strategyPattern.put("bar", new Bar());
        strategyPattern.put("bar", new Baz());
    }

    public Foo(String str) { // Constructor
        this.obj = strategyPattern.get(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create interface instead of object.
assume TestInterface is an interface having same methods which are in Bar and Buz.

interface TestInterface {

```
        testMethod1();

        testMethod2();

        }

        class Bar implements TestInterface{
         testMethod1(){
          // Your  code
        }

        testMethod1(){
          // Your  code
        }

        }


        class Baz implements TestInterface{
         testMethod1(){
          // Your  code
        }

        testMethod2(){
          // Your  code
        }

        }

        public class Foo {
            TestInterface obj; // Here change object to interface 
            public Foo(String str){ // Constructor
                if(str.equals("bar")){
                    this.obj = new Bar();
                }
                else{
                    this.obj = new Baz();
                }
            }




        Foo foo = new Foo("Bar");
```